# Deleting an entry from Arraylist using java stream which is used as value in hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-stream

```
Map<String, List<String>> HOSTING = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
HOSTING.put("1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","45","54")));
HOSTING.put("2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","62","54")));
HOSTING.put("3", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","45","64")));
HOSTING.put("4", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("37","45","54")));
```

I want to delete "62" from key "2".

Expected output

HOSTING={1=[23, 45, 54], 2=[23, 54], 3=[23, 45, 64], 4=[37, 45, 54]}

I know how to do this but i want to know how to do it using java stream.

```
Collection<List<String>> result = HOSTING.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> "2".equals(e.getKey()))    
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)    
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This will just give me arraylist if that key is present in hashmap. I also thought of using nested stream and predicates.

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: Collection<List<String>> result = HOSTING.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> "2".equals(e.getKey()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));  This will just give me arraylist if that key is present in hashmap. I also thought of using nested stream and predicates.

Comment: @nauki Welcome to SO! Please read this article to [write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Start by telling us what you are trying to do, what you tried (code, examples), and what your end goal is. Avoid putting the necessary details in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
Map<String, List<String>> HOSTING = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
HOSTING.put("1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","45","54")));
HOSTING.put("2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","62","54")));
HOSTING.put("3", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23","45","64")));
HOSTING.put("4", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("37","45","54")));

System.out.println(HOSTING);
HOSTING.get("2").remove("62");
System.out.println(HOSTING);
```

Prints

```
{1=[23, 45, 54], 2=[23, 62, 54], 3=[23, 45, 64], 4=[37, 45, 54]}
{1=[23, 45, 54], 2=[23, 54], 3=[23, 45, 64], 4=[37, 45, 54]}
```

Or with a stream. Note: This is a kludge that simply uses a map to access the appropriate entry and alter the appropriate value in the list.  The remove method returns a boolean as to whether the value was removed so in both cases the ternary returns the `entry`.

```
HOSTING = HOSTING.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> (e.getKey().equals("2")
                && e.getValue().remove("62")) ? e : e)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                Entry::getValue));
        
System.out.println(HOSTING);
```

Prints

```
{1=[23, 45, 54], 2=[23, 54], 3=[23, 45, 64], 4=[37, 45, 54]}
```

But I do not recommend using streams to do this.